# What has happened to Sora's Family?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

In Kingdom Hearts, Sora has started his adventure unwanted after the Heartless invaded Destiny Island.

He then saves the worlds and Destiny Island is recreated (as seen in Kingdom Hearts II, where Kairi and Selphie are going to school and to the beach, also in the ending sequence of Kingdom hearts and Kingdom Hearts II).

When his adventure began, he wanted to create a raft with Riku and Kairi. When the Heartless came, there was a storm, so Sora went to the little Island immediately.

**BUT here is the heart of the question: When he went to the island where the raft lies, a woman, presumably his mother called for him. 
Is this woman related to Sora ever mentioned again?**

Kairis relatives were probably swallowed by the Darkness in Radiant Garden.
About Rikus family, there is as far as I know never mentioned anything.

But Sora has at least one relative, which seems like he doesn't care for them or didn't had any bonds to them (which I can't believe, because he worships friendship so much).

Comment: This has bothered me ever since I played Kingdom Hearts, and now it has resurfaced to bother me again.  Sadly, I think this might just be a case of forgotten parents.

Comment: Maybe I just haven't payed enough attention and someone here did. This can't be forgotten.

Comment: "BUT here is heart of the question:" Well, let's dive deep into the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Sora went to the adventure in KH1 he did it unintentionally.
There was a storm that swallowed him forcefully and send him to another dimension (also seems as world).
It happend because Riku opened the Door To Darkness and it led to unstable connetion between all of the worlds who connected to his home town.
As for your question, Sora was determined in all of his journey (KH1,2) to bring back his friend home in one piece (and he succeeded ☺).
He didnt have the privilege (because of promise he made with donald and goofy) or the time to think about his rest of his family.

So it's not like he forgot them or anything like that, he made his way one task at the time.

Comment: Nice answer, but after Kingdom Hearts 2 he sits there peacefully with Kairi and Riku on Destiny Island. So there would be enough time to say hello to his family. But then there is suddenly Dream Drop Distance and Coded, followed by Kingdom Hearts 3.

Comment: @souichiro First of all, Coded was a filler and it wasn't really concern me to have a non relevant storyline. In Dream Drop Distance (and probably KH3) Sora and Riku was summoned personally by king micky and Yen Sid for helping them to find one more guardian of light and defeat once again Xehanort.
If Sora or Riku has any conversation between them and their families it wasnt realy relevant either.

Answer (score -1):

Sora's family is only mentioned in the one game, and has yet to ever be mentioned again. I personally am confused about why Sora's mother and if he had any other family would just disappear.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. I'm sure the OP will find your input helpful, but this probably would have been better left as a comment, as it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: After contributing for awhile, you will gain reputation, and be able to [post comments everywhere](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Until then, start by reading through the help center, and reading through other good questions and answers.